# Is it ethical to tell my teaching assistant that I like him?

Tags: ethics, united-states, interpersonal-issues, teaching-assistant

I, a twenty-year-old female, have come to admire the graduate teaching assistant for my summer course quite strongly. I'm extremely interested in what he has to say, I always pay attention, never use my phone and use eye contact to show interest. I do like them very much and I think about them with warmth often. I want to know about their work, I want to know what he is interested in. I would like to at least be their friend.

Despite my strong admiration I must emphasize that I have not and do not plan to cross professional boundaries until the end of the course.

I have spoken to them though it was only a short conversation about the work that was assigned to us the following weekend, however he did seem quite warm and open to conversation. Specifically he emphasizes in his syllabus to not hesitate to contact him with any questions we may have at all. I would like to be able to talk to them more without bothering them, and over stepping professional boundaries. I hopefully plan to ask them out once the course has ended, but I would still like to be able to have the chance to talk to them too as friends outside of course hours about the course material. Would this be ethical? Should I just back down? Specifically I wanted to thank him for giving me a very positive, in-depth feed back in the essay assignment that I had turned in that I got a perfect grade on.

I've been going through a really rough time in my personal life. Despite having flunked before, I made a promise to myself to work harder and to never give up on my goals. Truly their receptiveness, warmth and passion has genuinely inspired me to keep going and to study harder. I would very much like to thank them for inspiring me and being a good teacher which has helped me understand the material.

- Would it be ethical to express these sentiments of admiration and gratitude to them during their office hours?
- Would it be possible to date them after the course has ended since he is essentially a normal graduate student instead of a true professor?

*edit
Class has ended and we have a date planned! Thanks all for your advice!

*edit #2
We are still dating and our 9 month anniversary is coming up soon! The relationship is going really well and it is the best and most loving relationship we’ve ever been in! we are both doing fantastic!
Thanks for all your help ! (May 7th 2020)

*edit # 3
Not sure if anyone comes across this anymore but our one year anniversary passed a few months ago and we're growing strong! I'm really happy that I went out of my comfort zone and found a lasting relationship. (10/28/2020)

Comment: Answers in comments, further life advice, and extended discussion have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96553/discussion-on-question-by-apollogie-is-it-ethical-to-tell-my-teaching-assistant). Please read [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230/7734) before posting another comment.

Comment: Congrats on your anniversary!

Comment: Congratulations! And many thanks for the update!

Comment: What a lovely story. Really nice to read this.

Comment: Yeah, people reads the update. That's an amazing story, thanks for providing an edit, I do hope you will both keep finding happiness in this relationship.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your sweet wishes and kind words <3

Comment: This post is cute. Because when I was in school, people were trying to hit on the teach assistants all the time without reservation.

Comment: What a lovely and heartwarming story one occasionally finds while serendipitously browsing the time sink that is SE. Please post a further update when you get married ;-)

Comment: To express gratitude is ALWAYS good.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Wait until after the course is over and grades are in: don't put your TA in a difficult situation.

After that, you are just two adult humans, assuming you won't have any other courses with this TA.

Comment: However, they will still be working and studying in the same department, so some care is needed. Be prepared to handle a "No interested" answer gracefully.

Comment: We actually are majoring in different things. I’m getting a bachelors with a plan to get a masters in clinical psych and he is a history PhD candidate. He’s teaching one of the core classes I missed taking when I dropped out for my health.

Comment: @apollogie That makes it less likely you'll interact again professionally so that makes it easier, but Patricia's suggestion to be prepared to handle a "not interested" answer is still very important: you need to be prepared that he may not be interested. That can be difficult when you feel like you know someone well but don't actually have a personal relationship with yet, so just be aware of that and ready, and keep your hopes measured.

Comment: You can mention it after the course, but you might well get a polite 'not interested' answer, especially if they are there to work and to work only.

Comment: @Tom that makes sense. I’m scared of getting hurt again so maybe it’s best I move on

Comment: That's down to you, but if you see being told 'I'm not interested' as something which is going to hurt you, I would perhaps move on as that is understandably going to be a common response in academia.  You could perhaps take up some activity outside of academia and see if you meet someone that you get on with there?

Comment: @Tom Restricting one's dating pool to non-academics is no protection against rejection.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not trying to imply that at all, I'm saying most people I know tend to have better luck in that area just meeting people outside of their work environment, I'm not saying they have to be non-academics.  Also, it's positive if you see it that way as it will get you to meet new people and take up new activities.

Comment: @apollogie, if you never risk the "not interested" answer, then you're guaranteeing it by answering the question negatively for them. Give him the opportunity to answer for himself and you won't have to wonder later in life what the answer could have been. Maybe the answer will be actually be "interested".

Answer (score 104):

I'd like to add that there is another reason for waiting until the class have been over for a while.  There's a phenomenon of "love for authority."  It happens a lot in academia, where the instructor would otherwise not be that interesting, but because of the moderate position of power (and the things that go with it, like being the perceived leader, self-confidence, etc) he is much more attractive.  It could be that a month after the course is over, your TA will fade back into his proper level.

Love relationships based on an unequal balance of power are usually unhealthy.   You probably want to make sure that you're really attracted to him and not just his position.

Consider the other person's feelings in this as well.  They could fall for you based on your attraction to them.  If you find out later that your attraction was solely or mostly because of the teacher-student dynamic, it could be pretty hard for them when you break it off.

Comment: And too often, the instructor, IRL, turns out to be incredibly boring. I know _I_ am.

Comment: @Buffy  Right.  In real life I'm a complete introvert.  My classroom personality, where I'm witty, outgoing, and in charge is a complete fabrication.  My idea of an evening of fun is a cigar and a beer on the deck with no one bothering me.

Comment: @B.Goddard I think the healthiness of unequal power in a relationship depends on what you mean by "unequal balance of power". There's a difference between a teacher and their student starting a relationship and a consentual BDSM relationship with a negotiated power exchange.

Comment: While I do like older men and have dated older men, I truly feel this time is different. I’m attracted to his looks but I’m also attracted to how he actually is really shy when he’s lecturing. He crosses his legs and coughs and chokes because he doesn’t swallow enough saliva out of nervousness. To me this comes across as he’s more likely a gentle self conscious person as am I. (Hence the play on words with my username)

Comment: Be careful!   I can tell you as a teacher I stay away from this issue for reasons having nothing whatsoever to do with the individual.  This might put the TA in a tough spot no matter how they feel about you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I’ll just wait until the end and accept whatever happens. I should be focusing on my study’s anyway right now

Comment: @B.Goddard Complete fabrication? I understand it may not your self as it is, but I would not describe your job like that

Comment: @Ooker  I'm pretty far down the spectrum.  It took years of experimenting, and many missteps, to build a robotic facade to use in the classroom.  I don't think any of my jokes are funny, but I've figured out how to make the class laugh.  On evaluations, I get many comments about how I'm a very different person in office hours than I am in lecture.  I would describe my job has a monumental struggle.  I figured out a way to feed myself.  But I have never understood why so many people in academia didn't want me to eat.  There is a lot of bigotry in academia against the neurologically different.

Comment: I cannot speak for them, and I don't have problem with having to wear a mask. I just don't understand that after so many years wearing it, the mask does not become a part of yourself. I mean it in a positive meaning. I guess most people would just change their personality to fit it. I don't understand why you don't understand why your jokes work. You have *mastered* that joke, after all.

Comment: @Ooker jokes in class need to be just a tiny bit witty with the current subject to be "funny" for the class. I know I laughed for that in class. It just eases the mood. And students will take it for that. A really complex joke might get over the head of too many people desperatly trying to follow what the instructor says, and when only few laugh it gets cringy for them.

Comment: @Ooker Actors **prepare** for roles as murderers, aliens, or "hard-boiled" cops but that doesn't mean they are murdering alien "hard-boiled" cops. I've known many teachers who are very active, passionate, and animated in their lectures but when researching together they are almost opposite. The difference is the **preparation** and the ability to *"play the role"* of professor in class. So, with the *joke* example, the time to prepare, deliver, edit, re-deliver, etc. a joke to a class doesn't mean you get it, it means you see it land. Not saying this is B.G.'s reason just that it happens

Comment: @Ooker  I "get" my jokes, it just don't find them funny.  Some people would laugh at an old lady falling down the stairs and some wouldn't.  But delivery is everything.  I copy Bob Newhart and that works well for me:  Deadpan and a little hesitant delay at the right point and even Calculus is funny.

Comment: @B.Goddard cigar and beer with no-one bothering you? That is living the dream, my friend.

Answer (score 31):

> Would it be ethical to express these sentiments of admiration and gratitude to them during their office hours?

Of course. I would wait until the course, and the grades, are finalized, though. Consider sending a note or expressing your (professional) sentiments during TA evaluations (if such a thing exists where you are); doing it in office hours might be uncomfortable.

> Would it be possible to date them after the course has ended since they are essentially a normal graduate student instead of a true professor ?

You would have to check your university's rules. In general, there are no policies prohibiting this sort of relationship, if you will have no future courses together. The TA in question might be concerned about the appearance of impropriety, however.

> As an artist, would it be strange to ask them if i could give them a drawing?

Of course you should not give them anything until the course, and the grades, are finalized. As to strangeness, that's maybe an interpersonal issue -- for me, yes, I would certainly find it strange, but that's not to say I wouldn't think it was awesome, especially if I liked the student.

It gets more complicated since you plan to ask him out though -- if you give it, then ask him out, that's a bit uncomfortable; if you ask him out and are turned down, it's a bit awkward to give him the artwork anyway.

Comment: As an instructor, I've gotten a few drawings and paintings from students. Nothing strange about it. Typically, this happens after the course ends.

Comment: Guys the sketch is so nice but im probably too nervous to give it to them afterwards anyway. I dont want to be like " hey look at this sketch i made of a photo i found online about your phd?" I have no idea how to bring this up, i should probably keep it to myself lol.

Comment: @42- theres actually a case of one of my acquaintance who ended up dating her TA after the course ended. So it is allowed, as long as they arent student teacher dynamic. They work together tutoring extra curricular now as well. The power of love am i right. Two brains are better than one.

Comment: Don't send anything personal during TA evaluations. The bare minimum would be to wait until everything about the course was complete.

Comment: @apollogie Yeah I really think you should keep your drawing. It might seem like a good idea from your perspective but you might just scare him off. Remember, show interest, not obsession. That's a real turn-off. I'm exaggerating, but basically "Hey I think you're cute" works much better than "Omg you're so perfect just date me now" (don't take this too hard but it's good to have it in mind. Try to balance your shown interest!)

Comment: @GregMartin - yes, I meant expressing "sentiments of admiration and gratitude" during TA evaluations, not asking him out during TA evaluations. Updated my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: @teleporting goat no that totally makes sense thanks

Answer (score 14):

First: Nothing wrong with you - many of us had/have colleagues they deeply admire and potentially want some kind of personal relationship with (and sometimes that works out), not such an unusual situation.

> I wish i could request to transfer myself out lol.

So why don't you? If there is another TA, you can ask the professor to move. Then ask the TA out for a coffee to explain why you moved.

> Would it be ethical to express these sentiments of admiration and gratitude to them during their office hours?

If you show gratitude or admiration be specific. No problem at all to thank for a specific hint or deed. Not a big deal in showing a moderate amount of admiration, like "i liked your slides".

However, if it is more that your conversation with him is based on your crush on him and not directed at a specific thing but at spending time with him, then don't forget, during his office hours he has not the simple option to just ask you to leave (it is his job to tutor), and maybe there are other students and time pressure - so ask yourself - if you would have a man make advances on you in your job under the pretext of the job, how would you like it in general as a female ? If it would be the other way round, people would consider it pretty obvious that such a behavior is not appropriate (obviously happens too often!).

> Would it be possible to date them after the course has ended since they are essentially a normal graduate student instead of a true professor?

Zero problem with that from a moral/ethical viewpoint, but

- check university rules
- avoid the appearance that it's related to the grading of the course in any way (if you date, be a little discrete for one or two months)

Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

Telling someone you are grateful for their help with your work is usually a good and kind thing to do.

In this case, however, you are not just grateful for their professional contributions, but interested in them as a person, potentially romantically. If your TA was aware of this it would make their job harder:

- they may worry that you are trying to bias them in your favour,
- they may worry that other people will think you are trying to bias them, so they have to try extra hard to demonstrate that they are not,
- they may worry that they are actually being subconsciously biased, and try to compensate for it, and then worry if they're overcompensating and being unfair,
- they may worry that you will be especially sensitive to receiving criticism from them, or you may interpret praise differently,
- if they find the attention uncomfortable, they can't just avoid social contact with you, because it's a necessary part of their job.

Until the course is over you are doing them a favour by keeping the personal aspect to yourself.

With that in mind, even expressing just professional gratitude carries some risk that you'll unintentionally – through your manner, nervousness, choice of words, whatever – signal the personal feelings you have.

The safe thing to do is to avoid standing out in the eyes of your TA until the course is over. That said, the unsafe thing does have potential upsides and I don't want to tell you that no-one should ever say something kind to someone else for fear of unwanted implications. But make sure when you're thinking about what you want to do that you're including the potential ways it can go badly for them, as well as for you.

Answer (score 7):

You won't have future courses with him, so **ethically** I expect it would be okay to get to know him *after* the course is over (as you said).

But you have a problem that hasn't directly been addressed in other answers.

> Would this be ethical? Should I just back down? Specifically I wanted to thank him for giving me a very positive, in-depth feed back in the essay assignment that I had turned in that I got a perfect grade on

Nothing wrong with doing that, but it might be awkward if he detects that you are interested in him.
He might feel obligated to put you at arms length (and he would be right to do so since he is currently your TA).

> Studying is so hard for this class now... Im trying really hard and i have an A but i find myself day dreaming about them at the same time.

That's great... except for the fact that you are in the middle of a relationship with him which he isn't participating in (yet). You need to reign it in some, or

1. by the time you tell him you are interested in him, you'll be much farther into this relationship than he is... that could scare him off.
2. or you could miss the mark with your assumptions but he is a great guy (and a great fit for you) but he isn't who you think he is...
   so you end up disappointed with a guy *that otherwise* would have been a great match for you.

Just slow down... you'll have a better chance after the course is over.

Also, I'd advise you to wait a few weeks after the course to contact him... if you contact him immediately, he may still feel like he is your TA and feel ethically compelled to turn you down.

Answer (score 6):

If you two enter a romantic relationship, then together with the existing TA-student relationship, you two are having a [dual relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_relationship). It is recommended to avoid this type of relationship, for the reason that other people have discussed.

However, just for the sake of the discussion, let's assume that you decide to enter it anyway. Then the prerequisite is that you two be aware of all the possible negative outcome that come to this, that the benefits outweigh the risks. Then you two will have to continually consciously remind yourselves that these relationships should not be mixed, and to continually answer people's challenges. Since this is a very serious problem, they will scrutinize it more than normal – in other words, they are skeptical that this ethically works. And persuading them is the same with making them having **cognitive dissonance**, which is an arduous task. All of these things will quickly drain a huge amount of your energy to do other things, including building your relationship.

So it's about whether you have the energy to get through all of this or not, and whether both of you decide that this energy is worth to spend on this or not.

Answer (score 3):

Wait until the course is over.
Think if they don't feel the same way. It is just awkward after that.

Stay focused on why you're there.
You've got time to enjoy your life.
Maybe he'll be a part of it but don't put a wrinkle in your road that may affect your course outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answers; my immediate thought was that you might try proposing - while not in a work context - that you date once the course is over. If you are really worried about the university's position on this matter you could always consider declaring the relationship with the administration.

I can empathise with your position having been attracted to three different scientists throughout my career to this point. However, I would never have the courage to initiate, since I would be mortified if the feelings were not reciprocal. And I know that the feelings almost certainly were not reciprocal.

As somebody else has said, it is possible that we are subconsciously attracted to people because of their position rather than because of their individuality, and maybe you will only be able to discern between these realities by trying the relationship.

I wish you all the best, and I hope you form a happy couple!

Answer (score -2):

> Would it be possible to date them after the course has ended since they are essentially a normal graduate student instead of a true professor?

I am going to disagree with the broad consensus of advice given here, which tells you to wait until after your course is over.  I realise that some universities (particularly in the US) have an absurdly Puritan sexual environment, but even accounting for this, the precaution to wait until the end of your course still seems unnecessary to me.  If you are romantically interested in this student, there is no reason that you cannot express your interest immediately.  And indeed, if you wait, he might get scooped up by someone else.

Since you are the undergraduate student in this encounter, and he is your teacher, it is unlikely that there is any ethical/professional restriction on your own expression of interest in him.  Bear in mind that *from his position*, it is likely that he will be under some professional/ethical restrictions on how he deals with this, since he is your teacher.  Even so, it should not be all that difficult for a graduate-student teaching assistant to deal with a situation in which he is considering becoming romantically involved with an undergraduate, or (hopefully not) considering turning her down.  University policies on this matter differ from institution to institution, but all that is likely to be involved is that he would disclose this to the course convener, and you might be assigned to a different class, or have your work marked by a different teaching assistant.

Contrary to the advice of others on this thread, there is absolutely no ethical reason to wait until the end of your course to express romantic interest in your teacher --- my advice: **[*carpe diem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpe_diem).**

Comment: Even if you as a student have no rules preventing you from doing this, your intended romantic partner (the TA) likely does. If you're really interested in having a relationship with them, it seems like you would want to avoid putting them in a bad spot where either they are forced to turn you down or you risk them looking unprofessional in front of a supervisor.

Comment: @Bitmapped but according to the answer, it's just simply an inconvenience for him rather than a career issue

Comment: Being asked out my a 20-year-old female admirer while in grad school does not put one in a "bad spot", and there is nothing "unprofessional" in having this occur.

Comment: I half agree with this – and admire its honesty. It is definitely your TAs problem as they are the one in the position of authority. But it is wrong to think the two of you will overcome the Freudian situation of the power dynamic. I'd strongly recommend transfering tutorial first, then telling them why. This may mean you won't get to hear from your favourite tutor anymore AND you find out their already in a relationship, but as Ben says, it may be worth that risk.

Comment: @Ooker Each institution has their own policy, but at my college, we've fired GTAs who became involved in relationships with students currently in their classes. Even if it is possible to transfer the student mid-semester to another instructor, the GTA or student are going to have to explain why. It's not going to reflect well on the GTA they tried to do this, and that could very well have career ramifications. It's much safer to wait until the end of the semester.

Comment: @Bitmapped: Has your institution fired TAs who were asked out by others, and then went to their course conveners to take the appropriate action to ensure they are not in a position of authority over that person while dating?  The fact that you think *being asked out* reflects badly on a TA, and would have negative career ramifications, is horrendous.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica A GTA cannot help if someone asks them out. But just because you're asked out doesn't mean you have to act on it, or act on it at that time. That's where the problem lies.

In the cases where GTAs were fired, they started dating the student while the student was still in their class. They did not seek to have the student transferred, but transferring between sections is an imperfect solution because of existing grades, imposes burdens on others, and may not be possible due to institutional policies.

Comment: Then you have completely conceded my point --- there is no inherent problem in the TA being asked out during the semester.  So long as the TA does the right thing subsequently, all is fine.